# Insert variable into django translate field

Tags: python, django, translate

They ask me to modify a web which I don't realy know how it was done, but it's made using django. I don't know much about python or django, so this question may be simpel. But I have this line whitch is translated in a po file:

```
<h3 class="event-title">{{ event.length.duration }} {% trans "WEEK PROGRAM" %}</h3>
```

I need to modify it to insert the event.length.duration inside the text, something like this:

```
{% trans {{ event.length.duration }} " WEEK PROGRAM" %}
```

Any Suggestion? Thanks

Edit:

Thanks to catavaran this question is solved.

Comment: Don't put solved in the title; this isn't a forum. The fact that it is answered is visible based on the color of the "answers" in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`{% blocktrans %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) template tag:

```
{% blocktrans with duration=event.length.duration %}{{ duration }} WEEK PROGRAM{% endblocktrans %}
```

`manage.py makemessages` understands this tag as well as the `{% trans %}` but if you write the `.po` file manually then translation should be:

```
msgid "%(duration)s WEEK PROGRAM"
msgstr "PROGRAMA %(duration)s SEMANAS"
```

Comment: Thank you, catavaran. It seams to work. But I have this on mi po file:

#: frontend/templates/events/list.html:19
msgid "{duration} WEEK PROGRAM"
msgstr "PROGRAMA {duration} SEMANAS"

And, wen I load the page it dosen't recognice the translation.

Thank you very much